# unable to make logstash read file from beginning after every restart of logstash (without the file being changed)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Following code is in the input { file { } } of config file, but when I restart logstash, with the same file being "unchanged", logstash does NOT read file from beginning.

```
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "nil"
```

If I change anything and save the file, then logstash reads from the beginning.        Using windows OS.
I cannot keep changing the file everytime I want to test my config during development. Is this logstash bug? Any suggestions?     Thanks

Comment: I tried sincedb_path => "Nil", sincedb_path => "nil:", sincedb_path => "NILL"... did NOT work

Comment: Although not an "automagic" fix, what I've been doing is deleting the .sincedb file before I restart logstash. Most likely found in c:\users\{your_user}\.sincedb_{somevalue}. This is the file that tracks where the last file read left off in the log file. Of course, if you have any other files you don't want to "reset" for logstash, you may want to do something less extreme than just outright deleting it, but I haven't played with that enough to comment further on that.